# Is it might to check is there any open tab with special address in Firerfox in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs

I want to write an script to send selected text to google translate with java script. but any time that it runs the script opens a new tab of googletranslate.com.I want to add a function to check if would have existed open tab with same requested address it send to that tab and if not open a new tab with that address.

```
document.execCommand('copy');
window.open("https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fa&op=translate");
```

(it is not so important but if you help me how can I automatic paste of copied text from clipboard in last line of code you will give me a big help.)
Thanks.

Comment: Read documentation for things you use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the window name parameter (the second argument) to [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

```
document.execCommand('copy');
window.open("https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fa&op=translate", "translate");
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That will reuse the tab if possible. (The name can be anything you want other than one of the reserved window names like `_blank`.)

Comment: Thanks but it works just on one tab if i go another tab and run script again it will open another googletranslate tab special for it and in another tabs happen again!

Comment: @Ali.Ghzd - I'm afraid I didn't understand what you meant to say in that comment...?